# how to loop through each row of datatable in order to execute a function one by one for each row

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, datatable

I have a table in the database having a single column and multiple rows. What I am doing is iterating through each row of that table and calling a function to send mail for each row. But the problem is that function is getting executed for all the rows simultaneously whereas I want to execute it one by one for each row. Here is the code-

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GetAllRecipient();
            Msg = null;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);

        }
     public void SendHTMLMail(string emailAddress)
            {
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                Msg.To.Add(emailAddress);

           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/one.html"));
                string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Regex regx = new Regex("(?<!src=\")http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string output = regx.ToString();
                output = readFile;
                Msg.Body = output.ToString();
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                int i = 0;
                string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);
                output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
                {

                    var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
                    url = url.Replace("%3F", "&").Replace("%3D", "=");
                    return $"http://10.10.10.12/MI/two?sender={username}&link={url}&mailer_id={i}";
                }));
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);
                Msg.Subject = null;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
            }
            public void GetAllRecipient()
            {
                if (RadioButton1.Checked)
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM address1";
                    cmd.Connection = sql;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sql.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    sql.Close();

                     //   for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
                      //  {
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)

                            {
                                SendHTMLMail(row["address"].ToString());

                            }

                       // }
                }

                else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    string connectionString = "";
                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                        {

                            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        con.Open();
                        DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        dAdapter.Fill(dt);
                        con.Close();


                      //  for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
                       // {
                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                SendHTMLMail(row["address"].ToString());

                            }

                      //  }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How do you know that it is "executing all rows simultaneously" ? your for-loop in the method `GetAllRecipient` is redondant

Comment: coz in my sent mail box, i saw that the mail got delivered to all of them together

Comment: For sample i entered two records in database. So now the mail is getting delivered twice- for the first time it is getting delivered to the first person i.e first row and for the second time it is getting delivered to both of them i.e. both the rows

Comment: ok - your for-loop was part of that problem. But it still doesn't sound like a concurrency problem. it is more of an iteration problem, and i think it was solved when you removed the for-loop :)

Comment: No! When i removed the outer for loop,  the mail is getting delivered twice- for the first time it is getting delivered to the first person i.e first row and for the second time it is getting delivered to both of them i.e. both the rows

Comment: why am i not able to send the mail individually. i am stuck at this since last week ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that demonstrates concurrency or parallelism. As it stands, it should be executing SendHTMLMail sequentially for each row and not concurrently. What makes you feel it is all happening at the same time? Also verify the implementation of SendHTMLMail is not async.

Comment: i have executed the code and the mail has been sent to all the recipients together. How to execute it concurrently. Why the mail is delivered to all of them rather then getting delivered separately

Comment: You mean one email was sent, with everybody's email in to the "To" field?

Comment: Well for starters, you have 2 loops iterating over the table.  This is enough: foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                            SendHTMLMail(row["address"].ToString());

                    }

Comment: You should remove the outer loop: for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++). Also, can you share the implementation for SendHTMLMail ?

Comment: i have remove that but now it is executing for two times. For sample i entered two records in database. So now the mail is getting delivered twice- for the first time it is getting delivered to the first person i.e first row and for the second time it is getting delivered to both of them i.e. both the rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178720/discussion-between-mehdi-ibrahim-and-manu-sharma).

Comment: Hey i wanna ask one more thing. Instead of entering email and password in textbox i want to  fetch the record from database. I want to send bulk mail and what i want is to send first 100 mails from one mail id, next 100 from second mail id and so on. And these ail ids and their corresponding passwords are to be fetched from database.

Comment: post a new question with your code and I will try to help.

Comment: i have posted the question. eveything is same like it was in this post. Rest information is on the post. here is the link-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143700/how-to-send-bulk-mails-using-multiple-e-mail-ids